# Google Gears Geolocation Simulator

Tags: google-gears

I'm trying to do something with Google Gears to get my GPS location and display some directions on a map, and I can make my changes, upload and then test on my Android phone, but it would be much easier if I could install Gears and then have some way to "simulate" a location on my desktop.

Has anyone done a Firefox Extension to override the location?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following link.

http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/

It's a wrapper for Gears and some other mechanisms to get the browser location.

It includes a set of routines that helps with simulation. Works in google chrome.